# Snap to only one item at a time and not more in android recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using LinearSnaphelper to snap to next item in a recyclerview  and it works fine. I see that if I do a fast snap it snaps by several items. Is there a possibility to restrict the snap to snap by 1 item irrespective of how fast user snaps?

Comment: are you having one item per screen?

Comment: @tamtom Yes. My screen can show at a time only one item. Each item occupies full width of the screen. Hence, I want the fast snap to restrict snapping to just one item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to your input, you need to replace `LinearSnapHelper` with [`PagerSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper.html)

By using `PagerSnapHelper` you can get the behavior like `ViewPager`